# Python Power Set of a List

Tags: python, powerset

I am trying to implement a function to generate the powerset of a list `xs`.

The general idea is that we walk through the elements of `xs` and choose whether to include `x` or not. The problem I'm facing is that `withX` ends up being equal to `[None]` (a singleton list with `None`) because (I think) `s.add(x)` returns `None`.

This isn't a homework assignment, it's an exercise in Cracking the Coding Interview.

```
def powerSetBF(xs):
    powerSet = [] 
    powerSet.append(set([]))
    for x in xs:
        powerSetCopy = powerSet[:]
        withX = [s.add(x) for s in powerSetCopy] # add x to the list of sets 
        powerSet = powerSet.extend(withX) # append those entries
    return powerSet
```

Comment: could you provide more context? exemplaric input and expected vs. actual output?

Comment: capturing return value of `[s.add(x) for s in powerSetCopy]` definitely wrong. It will always be a list of `None`s. `s.add(x)` returns `None`.

Comment: maybe related [print powerset of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632421/print-powerset-of-a-string)

Comment: @user2993016 there are quite a few mistakes in this code. e.g. `powerSet = powerSet.extend(withX)` will assign `None` to `powerSet`, as `extend` modifies in place and returns `None`. I recommend learning more about list manipulation in python.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the `powerset` example from the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "list(powerset([1,2,3])) --> [(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (1,2,3)]"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

For a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) of integers up to the length of the given list, make all possible [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) them together as one object.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recursive solution that does not use any modules:

```
def pset(myset):
  if not myset: # Empty list -> empty set
    return [set()]

  r = []
  for y in myset:
    sy = set((y,))
    for x in pset(myset - sy):
      if x not in r:
        r.extend([x, x|sy])
  return r

print(pset(set((1,2,3,4))))
#[set(), {1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {3}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {4}, 
# {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {1, 2, 4}, {3, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools

def powerset(L):
  pset = set()
  for n in xrange(len(L) + 1):
    for sset in itertools.combinations(L, n):
      pset.add(sset)
  return pset

powerset([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

result

```
set([(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 4), (4,), (), (2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 4)])
```

Source code for `itertools.combinations` can be found here which has a few neat optimizations:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: Note that that code in the docs is "roughly equivalent" to the source code of `itertools. combinations`, which is implemented in C, so it's more efficient than doing it in pure Python code.