# Finding all subsets of a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, powerset

I need to create a function that will be passed a list and will create a new list with all the subsets of the the original list. I have to write it all from scratch, so no importing from itertools.

**For Example:**

the list given be like `[1,2,3]` and I want an output like

```
[[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[2,3],[1,3],[1,2,3],[]]
```

Comment: have you tried something so far?

Comment: If you have to write it all from scratch, it's probably best that **you** write it instead of doing some `import code from StackOverflow`. However, if you have any specific question about a part that you don't understand, please make a specific question.

Comment: I guess, this is the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/whats-a-good-way-to-combinate-through-a-set and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626379/python-power-set-of-a-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's a good way to combinate through a set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/whats-a-good-way-to-combinate-through-a-set)

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import combinations
s = set([1,2,3])
sum(map(lambda r: list(combinations(s, r)), range(1, len(s)+1)), [])
```

Producing tuples value but it close enough for you.